# Split a document in two independent parts

Tags: split

I want to have in the same latex file the main text and a supplemental material (SM). The SM will come after the main text, but I would like the figures to be labeled from 1 again (for example in the main text I have Fig 1, Fig 2 ... while in the SM I have Fig SM 1, Fig SM 2). However, I would like the references in the SM to continue the ones in the main paper (there will be a new "References" section in the SM). Is there an easy way to achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Please clarify the role of the "supplemental material" part of the document. E.g., is it functionally similar to an appendix?

Comment: Welcome. // Try to sketch one or two simple skeletons, and fill them with blindtext https://ctan.org/pkg/blindtext or lipsum https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum, if needed. EDIT your questoin and add the code(s) there. Thanks

Comment: Would the "supplemental materials" part contain several sections/chapters or just a single section/chapter?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? There are two separate files (actually three including the `*.bib` file) stored in the same directory (in this example). The main file contains all normal article material including a full reference list. The supplemental material is stored in a separate file and uses its own reference list.

The main file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[]{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Fig.}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
    @article{zeybek2020,
        title = {Analysis of pre-service teachers' learning styles according to {{V}}ermunt learning style model},
        author = {Zeybek, Gülçin and Şentürk, Cihad},
        date = {2020},
        journaltitle = {International Online Journal of Education and Teaching},
        volume = {7},
        number = {2},
        pages = {669--682},
        url = {https://iojet.org/index.php/IOJET/article/view/766},
        urldate = {2022-11-14},
        langid = {english}
    }
    @book{meltzer2018,
        title = {Executive Function in Education. {F}rom Theory to Practice},
        editor = {Meltzer, Lynn},
        date = {2018},
        edition = {2},
        publisher = {{The Guilford Press}},
        location = {{New York}},
        isbn = {978-1-4625-3453-1},
        langid = {english},
        pagetotal = {396},
        keywords = {classroom,education,executive function}
    }
    @article{vermunt2004,
        title = {Patterns in Student Learning: {{Relationships}} between Learning Strategies, Conceptions of Learning, and Learning Orientations},
        shorttitle = {Patterns in Student Learning},
        author = {Vermunt, Jan D. and Vermetten, Yvonne J.},
        date = {2004},
        journaltitle = {Educational Psychology Review},
        volume = {16},
        number = {4},
        pages = {359--384},
        doi = {10.1007/s10648-004-0005-y},
        langid = {english}
    }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{refsection}
        
    \section{A section with some text}
    
    \lipsum[1] as stated in \parencite{meltzer2018} \citeauthor{vermunt2004} and \cite{zeybek2020}
    
    \section{A section with text and figure}
    
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a.png}
        \caption{An example of a figure}
    \end{figure}

    \section*{References}

        \printbibliography[heading=none] 
    
    \end{refsection}

\clearpage

    \input{supplement}

\end{document}
```

The supplementary material file is loaded by the `\input` command and looks like this:

```
% Supplementary Material

\begin{refsection}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=SM Fig.}
  
\section*{Supplementary stuff}

    \lipsum[3]  \parencite{vermunt2004}
    
\subsection*{Some additional figures}
    
    \lipsum[4][2-4]
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-b.png}
        \caption{An example of another figure}
    \end{figure}
    
\section*{References}
    \printbibliography[heading=none]
    
\end{refsection}
```

Mind you: you cannot compile this file. Just add all info you want and save it as `supplement.tex`. Compile via the main file.

This main file example will result in this PDF output:

[image: main_supplement_split]